# finding the vector components of a normal line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

given the equation of a plane: 
ax + by = c.

I have seen several places where it is being said that the normal vector to the plane has the components `<a, b>`. However, i am yet to find any satisfying proof for this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be a point of the plane.

the equation of the plane can be written as

$$a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$$

on the other hand

let $\vec{n}=(A,B,C)$ be the normal to the plane .

the plane can also be defined as the set of point $M(x,y,z)$ such that

$$\vec{PM}.\vec{n}=0$$ or

$$A(x-x_0)+B(y-y_0)+C(z-z_0)=0$$ thus

we can take

$$\vec{n}=(a,b,c).$$

Comment: why ? your answer is ok and clear (+1)

Answer (score 0):

**hint:** $ax + by + 0z = c\implies \vec{n} = <a,b,0> = <a,b>$ as viewed in the $2$ dimensional case.

Comment: Ok. let's look at it this way:

Comment: the plane equation above in slope-int form is: y = (-a/b)x - c/b which means that the slope = -a/b, hence slope of the normal line = b/a. Does this not imply that the equation of the normal will be: y = (b/a)x + d, in which case the standard form is: -bx + ay = ad. If that is correct, why then is the normal vector components not <-b, a>

Comment: My suspicion is that the mention of "plane" in the body of the Question was mistaken (the title speaks of "normal line" instead, and other notation of the Question seems clearly two-dimensional).

Answer (score 0):

Take any two points $M_0\,(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $M_1\,(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ in the place. From the equations satisfied by these points:
$$ax_0+by_0=c=ax_1+by_1,$$
we deduce
$$a(x_1-x_0)+b(y_1-y_0)=a(x_1-x_0)+b(y_1-y_0)+0(z_1-z_0)=0,$$
which means the vectors $\vec n\,(a,b,0)$ and  $\overrightarrow{M_0M_1}$ are orthogonal.